# Pressing back in navigationcontroller triggered update. But to update ignored tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a problem , I have one available repose collection ViewController. At the same representation have a button switch to another View. Between the repose organized transitions (navigation controller). Clicking on the back button in the second presentation is called ViewDidAppear is good. But I also have an application has tabBarController. And when you click on the first View on the panel tabBar called again ViewDidAppear. Although he no longer needs to be called . Tell me how can I do so that does not cause tabbar ViewDidAppear. A caused only navigationController? ViewDidLayout almost perfect. But the update is activated twice. And if you do not swipe left and bring it to the end anyway, this event is called
Thank you!

Comment: `C#` and `monotouch` tags are inappropriate here, right?

Comment: i think a global bool variable will do your work.

Comment: @pawan Write an example please.

Comment: @nhgrif You could say, there functions the same only the language of the other. So what advice both mono and the xcode welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution!

```
bool loaded = false;
    public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
    { 
        if (!loaded) {
            LoadData ();
            loaded = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it sounds like you need a quick explanation of the different methods in `UIViewController`.

- If you need something to happen only once in your controller's lifetime: use `ViewDidLoad`
- If you need something to reload every time you return your controller: use `ViewWillAppear`
- If `ViewWillAppear` doesn't work for a weird situation (such as a timing issue), use `ViewDidAppear`
- Use `ViewDidUpdateLayout` or `ViewDidLayoutSubviews` if you need to perform layout adjustments in your controller, but this work is better done in a `UIView` subclass in my opinion.

Does this solve your problem? It sounds like you need `ViewDidLoad`, but your question is bit hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! ViewWillAppear - works almost right, but it works with navigationcontroller and tabcontroller. And I do not want an event triggered by clicking on the panel at the bottom of the screen. ViewDidAppear for the same reason is not suitable. ViewDidLayoutSubviews fulfills reason twice . ViewDidUpdateLayout - no such device .

Comment: So you need a method that happens only once? Use `ViewDidLoad`.

Comment: A little something when I get back to the submission button. That is not the function is performed viewdidload

Comment: `ViewWillAppear`/`ViewDidAppear` both happen every time if a tab bar switches views and if a navigation controller switches views. I'm having trouble following what you need. If there is a specific case you need to ignore the view appearing, can you set a boolean member variable in your controller that says something like `skipNextViewDidAppear = true;`, and then ignore the event where needed.

Comment: ViewWillLayoutSubviews performed only when the button is pressed back. I added a solution. Do you think it is good? :)